# R - Grabbing the index of the first occurrence of a value after a refresh point?

Tags: r, vector, sequence

Let's say I have a vector:

```
vec <- c(3,0,1,3,0,1,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,3,1,3)
```

I want to obtain the index of the first occurrence of 1 after every 3. So, the output of indices I want is

```
3,6,13,15
```

How would I do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use `cumsum` to keep track of 3s.

```
mat <- cbind(cumsum(vec==3), vec == 1)
which(!duplicated(mat) & mat[,2] & mat[,1] > 0)
[1]  3  6 13 15
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(as.vector(tapply(seq_along(vec) * (vec== 1), rleid(vec == 3), FUN = function(x)x[x  > 0][1])))
#[1]  3  6 13 15
```